# Android Emulator No Internet when using tethered iPhone

Tags: android, networking

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days.

My Android Emulator does not have access to the Internet on Mac OS X when I use my iPhone's tethered Internet connection. I often use this connection whenever working on the go, so it's quite frustrating when it doesn't work.

I've tried the following:

1. Setting DNS and running emulator from command line.

   ./emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_26 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
2. Removing network connections except the tethered connection from Mac OS Networking.

[image: Network Interfaces]

3. Deleting and reinstalling the AVD.

Looking at the logs, the only networking related errors I get are:

```
D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101]: PROBE_FALLBACK http://www.google.com/gen_204 Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.google.com": No address associated with hostname
I/qemu-props: start adbd ...
```

and

```
D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101]: PROBE_DNS www.google.com 78245ms FAIL
D/NetworkMonitor/NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101]: PROBE_HTTPS https://www.google.com/generate_204 Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.google.com": No address associated with hostname
D/ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101] validation failed
D/WifiStateMachine: NETWORK_STATUS_UNWANTED_VALIDATION_FAILED
```

I feel like the simulator is still trying to use WiFi even though the WiFi device has been removed.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I can't use the emulator with network when using my iPhone tethering either!

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. After setting Google's DNS on my host machine I restarted the Emulator. This allowed the Emulator to configure itself using Google's DNS, and now internet works in the emulator while tethering.